# how to check if the data being entered exists already

Tags: vb.net

here is my code to submit data to my csv file. How do I check to see if the data already exists before saving it.

```
Dim csvFile As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\HoseData.csv"

Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)

    'If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(csvFile) Then

'outFile.WriteLine("job number, sales order number, date, requested by, serial number, hose type, hose size, fitting 1, fitting 2, qty, oal, cut off, offset, crimp 1, crimp 2, cleaned, pigged", False)

    'End If

outFile.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text & "," & TextBox2.Text & "," & """" & DateTimePicker1.Text & """" & "," & ComboBox1.Text & "," & TextBox3.Text & "," & ListBox2.Text & "," & ListBox3.Text & "," & TextBox11.Text & "," & TextBox12.Text & "," & NumericUpDown1.TextAlign & "," & TextBox4.Text & "," & TextBox5.Text & "," & TextBox6.Text & "," & TextBox9.Text & "," & TextBox10.Text & "," & ListBox4.Text & "," & ListBox5.Text)

        MessageBox.Show("INPUT WAS SAVED")


        Dim butt As System.Windows.Forms.Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)
        butt.Enabled = False

        'butt.Visible = False
        outFile.Close()

        Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(csvFile))
```

Comment: How big, in the normal course of operations, will the file get?

Comment: It can be huge, infinite i assume

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
    Dim fn As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\HoseData.csv"
    Dim fileText As String
    Dim outString As String = TextBox1.Text & "," & TextBox2.Text & "," & """" & DateTimePicker1.Text & """" & "," & ComboBox1.Text & "," & TextBox3.Text & "," & ListBox2.Text & "," & ListBox3.Text & "," & TextBox11.Text & "," & TextBox12.Text & "," & NumericUpDown1.TextAlign & "," & TextBox4.Text & "," & TextBox5.Text & "," & TextBox6.Text & "," & TextBox9.Text & "," & TextBox10.Text & "," & ListBox4.Text & "," & ListBox5.Text
    Using reader As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fn)
        fileText = reader.ReadToEnd
    End Using
    Using outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(fn, True)
        If fileText.Contains(outString) Then
            'do stuff when the string is already present, e.g.:
            MessageBox.Show("You've already entered that one.")
        Else
            'do stuff when it isn't, e.g.:
            outFile.WriteLine(outString)
        End If
    End Using
```

Comment: it keeps crashing...idk im so lost. Im new to vb

Comment: What does "crashing" mean? When trying to execute what line does it fail?

Comment: it says the process cannot access the file HoseData.csv becuase it is being used by another process....

Comment: so should I block out the file I wrote and replace it with yours?

Comment: I just added a couple lines from your code above so that my code would be more autonomous instead of just an example. If you comment your code out, put my code in and run it, what happens? Same error? If so, save everything, reboot and try again. What happens?

Comment: it says the file cannot be accessed bc it is being used by another process...the error pops up on the my.computer.filesystem line

Comment: That same error happens the first time after a reboot? Does your application access the file anywhere else? Do you have another application accessing it?

Comment: Try using `ReadAllText` **before** you've opened it for writing with `OpenTextFileWriter`.  You're trying to do two things with the file at the same time...

Comment: nothing seems to be working...I feel like a for each loop or something is needed to go through each line while the file is running. I tried but im not positive how to do it. I had a class in c#. Everything is so different in vb

Comment: OK, comment everything out and then plug in the second block of code above. Does that alone work?

Comment: it works, to an extent. When I hit save, the data itself doesnt save, but the program doesnt crash

Comment: And it wrote the contents of the file to the output window?

Comment: So how about the code in my answer now? I integrated pieces of the two blocks with bits of your stuff.